# Draw routines only erratically executing in javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, drawimage

```
temp=document.getElementById("temp");
tempctx=temp.getContext("2d");
card=document.getElementById("card");
cardctx=card.getContext("2d");
cardctx.save();

for(i=0; i<14; i++)
{
    cardctx.restore();
    cardctx.clearRect(0,0,card.width,card.height);
    cardctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
    cardctx.drawImage(dragons[cardlist[i]],30,-110);
    tempctx.drawImage(card,cardX[i]-10,cardY[i]-30);
}
```

All the images in the dragons array are different, and the cardlist puts them in a random order. Debugging shows that these numbers are being passed correctly. My problem is that instead of getting random dragons, rotated sideways, and placed in their locations on the screen, I'm getting runs of 4 of the same dragon. Only when i=1,5,9,13 is it executing correctly, the other times I am getting duplicates of whatever came before. It is as though the clearRect command or perhaps the cardctx.drawImage command are only sometimes firing, or there is a delay, or things are being executed out of order. Has anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving your context outside of the loop and restoring it inside the loop.

You're also clearing the rect before you rotate the canvas.  Unless your card is transparent, you may not need to clear at all as the card would overwrite the current content.

Also, declare all your variables, that way you'll get errors if you have an accidental redeclaration.

I suspect you want to do something like this:

```
let temp=document.getElementById("temp");
let tempctx=temp.getContext("2d");
let card=document.getElementById("card");
let cardctx=card.getContext("2d");

for(let i=0; i<14; i++)
{
    cardctx.save();
    cardctx.rotate(Math.PI/2 * i);  // 90 degree increments for each card
    cardctx.clearRect(0,0,card.width,card.height);  // possibly not neccessary
    cardctx.drawImage(dragons[cardlist[i]],30,-110);
    tempctx.drawImage(card,cardX[i]-10,cardY[i]-30);
    cardctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that restore pops the save point off the stack. I thought I could keep going back to that same save point. So saving at the beginning and restoring at the end did the trick.